# How to make a reflection of an element in svg

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg, effects

Anyone know how to make a drawn svg elements (rect, text, etc.) have themselves reflected?? With JavaScript/JQuery

Any example with provided code will be great

If there is a JQuery plugin for that will also be great

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:
http://lea.verou.me/2011/06/css-reflections-for-firefox-with-moz-element-and-svg-masks/